# Change var img_list value with javascript or php

Tags: javascript, jquery

If

```
 <script>
                var img_list = 
    ["https:\/\/img3.example.me\/upload\/511bd439da25cc716e88a2e2ac0fb3ac.jpg"
        ,"https:\/\/img3.example.me\/upload\/77ac7d2ab7357ca181010905b228842d.jpg"
        ,"https:\/\/img3.example.me\/upload\/72387065c5464e8ce92297df783a2437.jpg"
];
            </script>
```

there is something like this 
I'd like to change this to

```
 <script>
                var img_list = 
    ["https:\/\/img3.example2.me\/upload\/511bd439da25cc716e88a2e2ac0fb3ac.jpg"
        ,"https:\/\/img3.example2.me\/upload\/77ac7d2ab7357ca181010905b228842d.jpg"
        ,"https:\/\/img3.example2.me\/upload\/72387065c5464e8ce92297df783a2437.jpg"
];
            </script>
```

Comment: aren't these both snippets not same?

Comment: example=>example2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `split` and `join`.Iterate over the array using `forEach` loop, `Split` the strings on `example` and `join` them using `example2` respectively.

```js
var img_list = 
    ["https:\/\/img3.example.me\/upload\/511bd439da25cc716e88a2e2ac0fb3ac.jpg"
        ,"https:\/\/img3.example.me\/upload\/77ac7d2ab7357ca181010905b228842d.jpg"
        ,"https:\/\/img3.example.me\/upload\/72387065c5464e8ce92297df783a2437.jpg"
];
var newlist=[];
img_list.forEach((e)=>{
newlist.push(e.split('example').join('example2'));
})
img_list=newlist;
console.log(img_list);
```

Comment: can i change the default img_list to newlist?

Comment: Yes, after adding example2 you can splice the old string and add the new one to it. Or you can just equate the new list to the old one

Comment: can you add what i want in your writing please?

Comment: I have made an edit, with the equal thing. You want the splice one too??